# Why is this off-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic

Question: [Using Apple's white tab bar in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204061/using-the-white-tab-bar-in-ios)

How is this off-topic at all?

Comment: I think it should be, **Not a Real Question**.

Comment: Not sure if I would have gone for off-topic. NARQ perhaps. But it's not a great question.

Comment: @Bart Why would it not be a real question?

Comment: Based on the answers you've received it does appear to be on topic so I've cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @IanCarroll Given the minimal nature of the question I might let it slide, but it shows no research effort for example. You don't demonstrate having done anything to solve your own problem here. Part of that is demonstrated in one of the answers. A user tells you to follow a particular tutorial. You then inform him you have done so, but this does not fit your needs. Had you put such information into your question, this user would not have had to waste his time on it. It's by no means a drama, but they are things to think of.

Comment: In 2009, such questions would have been legitimate. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1200621/1313143. This doesn't show any more research effort and is just as shortly written.

Comment: In 2009 site was new, questions where less and probably less stick rules, that's why those kind of question are valid. Now a days volume of users is very high, and new rules are created by community.

Comment: The question is short, yes, but I think people are being a little harsh here. It's a specific question with specific, programming-related answers. The only reason it was closed was due to the close vote queue: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1989166 . I see no reason to close this, short of a duplicate asked somewhere else.

Comment: Agreed with Bart here: even one more sentence like "I've read through XYZ tutorial, but the color is a little too pink" or "I found `immanentizeTheEschaton` in the docs, but that erased my hard drive" would go a long way towards improving the way such a short question is recieved. But also as he said, that isn't the end of the world -- just something to consider for next time -- and the question should not be closed.